# Knex/Jade: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, pug, knex.js

Trying to switch out Mongo and put in Postgres (in other words, similar code worked fine with Mongo). Getting `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` on the following code. I'm sure it's simple but I'm new to this whole stack so having trouble tying it together. Not a lot of examples on knex, so even though the docs are pretty good, I'm having trouble finding an example to copy.

I'm obviously pulling the right data but am stuck on how to get jade to display it.

Stack: Node/Express/Knex/Postgres/Jade

users.js

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  db.select().from('users').limit(1)
    .then(function(users) {
        console.dir(users)})
    .then(function(users) {
        res.render('users', {users: users})})
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error(error)
  })
});
```

users.jade

```
extends layout

block content
  h1 Users
  ul
    for user in users
      p 
        input(type="text", name="name", value="#{user.name}")
        input(type="text", name="admin", value="#{user.admin}")
        input(type="text", name="smsNumber", value="#{user.smsNumber}")
```

console

```
[ { uid: 1,
    name: 'Don',
    admin: 'true',
    smsNumber: '4077023951',
    created_at: null,
    updated_at: null } ]
```

browser at localhost:3000/users

```
C:\Users\dvande03\Personal\dailychallenge\views\users.jade:6 4| h1 Users 5| ul > 6| for user in users 7| p 8| input(type="text", name="name", value="#{user.name}") 9| input(type="text", name="admin", value="#{user.admin}") Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

TypeError: C:\Users\dvande03\Personal\dailychallenge\views\users.jade:6
    4|   h1 Users
    5|   ul
  > 6|     for user in users
    7|       p 
    8|         input(type="text", name="name", value="#{user.name}")
    9|         input(type="text", name="admin", value="#{user.admin}")

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\dvande03\Personal\dailychallenge\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:218:8), <anonymous>:51:31)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\dvande03\Personal\dailychallenge\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:218:8), <anonymous>:106:4)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\dvande03\Personal\dailychallenge\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:218:8), <anonymous>:119:22)
    at res (C:\Users\dvande03\Personal\dailychallenge\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:219:38)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (C:\Users\dvande03\Personal\dailychallenge\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:380:38)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (C:\Users\dvande03\Personal\dailychallenge\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:370:21)
    at View.exports.__express [as engine] (C:\Users\dvande03\Personal\dailychallenge\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:417:11)
    at View.render (C:\Users\dvande03\Personal\dailychallenge\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:126:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\dvande03\Personal\dailychallenge\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:639:10)
    at EventEmitter.render (C:\Users\dvande03\Personal\dailychallenge\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:591:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\dvande03\Personal\dailychallenge\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:961:7)
    at C:\Users\dvande03\Personal\dailychallenge\routes\users.js:11:13
    at tryCatcher (C:\Users\dvande03\Personal\dailychallenge\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\util.js:24:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\dvande03\Personal\dailychallenge\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:454:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (C:\Users\dvande03\Personal\dailychallenge\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:530:18)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\dvande03\Personal\dailychallenge\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:646:14)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

res.render should look like this: `res.render(view [, locals] [, callback])`, where `locals` is an object whose properties define local variables for the view.
In your case that means changing the line where you render to:

```
res.render('users', {users: users})
```

You pass an object with local variables to render. In the jade-file you use the keys in the object when you want to refer to the values.

Comment: I was ready to celebrate and get back to making progress because that was such a glaring omission on my part I was sure it was right. Thank you for taking the time to explain in detail why that should've worked.

Unfortunately, it didn't. I've edited the original users.js code above to reflect the change and added the browser output. It's the same as the output from the original but I figured it needed to be included.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it but I don't completely understand why. I commented out the console.dir before the render and it works. Is that because the users in the console.dir `.then` didn't pass to the render `.then`?

I accepted the answer above too because without that, I couldn't have gotten here. Thank you @tomtom.

Comment: I'm not sure, but my understanding of chaining with .then is that you have to return something in each part of the chain. So what happens if you  return users; after your console.dir?

Comment: That was exactly it, @tomtom. You have to pass something along to each part of the `.then`. Thanks for your help.